# Install TeamViewrer on Lubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, teamviewer

I have downloaded the latest version (13) of Teamvier directly from the website and now have my .deb file.  When I double click this file and click the "Install Package" option, it asks for my sudo password, but I then get an error of -

> Please check your installation medium and make sure your apt-cache is up to date

I opened terminal and ran

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then attempted to install again, but I received the same error.  What must I do in order to succesfully install this program?

**EDIT**
Full error when I run `dpkg` command from terminal

```
    owner@OwnerBackup:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i teamviewer_13.1.8286_i386.deb
    (Reading database ... 226294 files and directories currently installed.)
    Preparing to unpack teamviewer_13.1.8286_i386.deb ...
    Unpacking teamviewer (13.1.8286) over (13.1.8286) ...
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of teamviewer:
    teamviewer depends on libqt5x11extras5 (>= 5.2); however:
    Package libqt5x11extras5 is not installed.
     teamviewer depends on qtdeclarative5-qtquick2-plugin (>= 5.2) | qml-module-qtquick2 (>= 5.2); however:
    Package qtdeclarative5-qtquick2-plugin is not installed.
    Package qml-module-qtquick2 is not installed.
    teamviewer depends on qtdeclarative5-controls-plugin (>= 5.2) | qml-module-qtquick-controls (>= 5.2); however:
    Package qtdeclarative5-controls-plugin is not installed.
    Package qml-module-qtquick-controls is not installed.
 teamviewer depends on qtdeclarative5-dialogs-plugin (>= 5.2) | qml-module-qtquick-dialogs (>= 5.2); however:
    Package qtdeclarative5-dialogs-plugin is not installed.
    Package qml-module-qtquick-dialogs is not installed.
 teamviewer depends on qtdeclarative5-window-plugin (>= 5.2) | qml-module-qtquick-window2 (>= 5.2); however:
    Package qtdeclarative5-window-plugin is not installed.
    Package qml-module-qtquick-window
dpkg: error processing package teamviewer (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu3) ...
    Processing triggers for mime-support (3.58ubuntu1) ...
    Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
    Errors were encountered while processing:
       teamviewer
    owner@OwnerBackup:~/Downloads$
```

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo dpkg -i <path_to_teamviewer.deb>`

Comment: And also, in which folder have you stored the `.deb` package?

Comment: @Fanatique - the .deb file is saved in the Downloads folder.  If I run the dpgk command, I get a generic error of 'Errors were encountered while processing'

Comment: Is that the whole error? If not, can you post the full output of the command? (edit it into your post) Also it'd be nice to mention what Linux Distro & version you are running on.

Comment: The entire error reads 'Errors were encountered while processing: TeamViewer'  My Ubuntu Version is Ubuntu 15.10

Comment: That cannot be the full error. It most likely is an error for missing dependancies. Try running `sudo apt-get install -f` (this will try to fix and install any broken packages/dependancies)

Comment: Running the apt-get command I get an error on multiple lines of 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79791/discussion-between-fanatique-and-user2676140).

Comment: btw, newer apt-get can do this instead of using dpkg: apt-get install /path/to/your/teamviewer_13.1.8286_i386.deb , thus solving dependencies in one shot (or not installing anything if it can't). There has to be at least a "/" char for apt-get to accept to install a .deb file.